# Removing smaller image from cart list (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

what I'm trying to do here is to remove my smaller images from my mini cart and this seem I can't really find the correct directory to modify it. These are the code that I added in my function.php and my review-order.php.
[The attachment is my image of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE7qC.png)

review-order.php
`<?php $thumbnail= apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>`

Function.php

````
global $product; 
if (is_cart()){ echo "<style>#checkout_thumbnail{display:none;}</style>"; } 
$item_data = $cart_item_key['data']; 
$post = get_post($item_data->id); 
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($item_data->id, array( 100, 100)); 
echo '<div id="checkout_thumbnail" style="float: left; padding-right: 8px">' . $thumb . '</div> ' . $post->post_title; } add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', isa_woo_cart_attributes, 10, 2);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code filter on function.php it will remove the images from cart page:

```
function sv_remove_cart_product_link( $product_link, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    return $product->get_title();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'sv_remove_cart_product_link', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi Neal, thanks for the quick reply but I had placed the code in function php and it seems doesn't have any changes here. Is there anything I'm missing here? Cheers.

Comment: Ok there is one another option to remove it : you can add this CSS in your style sheet

.woocommerce table.cart .product-thumbnail { display:none !important; }

Comment: Hi Neal, thanks for your suggestions but is there any other way of not using css? Because I'm doing for it for marketing team and they try to reduce the usage of css as much as possible. Cheers.

Comment: functions.php : add_filter( ‘woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail’, ‘__return_false’ ); can try this

Comment: CSS and functio.php have no effect on it sorry to say.

Answer (score -1):

Add this css in style css

```
.woocommerce table.cart .product-thumbnail { display:none !important; }
```